# how do I correctly pass my pathL and pathR to load my images in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to python and I am using opencv. I have one button(btn_Convertir) that calls the method sustractBands that calls the method createImage, but it receives two parameters, the paths from two images that I am loading using QFileDialog. I want to pass the two paths as parameters in order to use imread from opencv, and I also want to use my methods createImageRed and createCyan, but I always get an error, how can I do it in python? Please help

this is my code

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic, QtCore
import cv2
import numpy as np

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('UI.ui', self)
        self.cb_tipos.addItems(["a", "b", "c"])
        self.show()

        self.abrir_izq.clicked.connect(self.openFileL)
        self.abrir_der.clicked.connect(self.openFileR)
        self.rb_matrices.clicked.connect(self.cambiarEstadoCombo)

        self.btn_Convertir.clicked.connect(self.sustractBands, pathL, pathR)

    def openFileL(self):
        pathL = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open image","",'Images (* .jpg)')
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(pathL)
        print self.im_izq.size()
        pixmap.scaled(self.im_izq.size(), QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)
        self.im_izq.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def openFileR(self):
        pathR = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open image","",'Images (* .jpg)')
        pixmapd = QtGui.QPixmap(pathR)
        pixmapd.scaled(self.im_der.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)
        self.im_der.setPixmap(pixmapd)

    def createImage(imgL, imgR):
        imgFinal = createImageRed(imgL) + createImageCyan(imgR)
        cv2.imwrite('Final.jpg', imgFinal)
        cv2.imshow("Finished", imgFinal)
        cv2.waitKey() 

    def createImageRed(imgL):
        imgL[:, :, 0] = 0
        imgL[:, :, 1] = 0
        return imgL 

    def createImageCyan(imgR):
        imgR[:, :, 2] = 0
        return imgR    

    def sustractBands(self, pathL, pathR):
        imgL = cv2.imread(pathL, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        imgR = cv2.imread(pathR, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        createImage(imgL, imgR)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: _but I always get an error_ Which one?

Comment: undefined name createImage, what is the correct way of passing this as parameters?

Comment: not an expert, but since they are class methods shouldn't they have `self` as first argument?

Comment: I tried also with global variables but it says it is no defined I am not understanding this language

Comment: I changed to self all the methods

Comment: Please I know it is not that hard just a hint

Comment: I'm not answering further because I know python probably less than you :D. Just wait for an answer from somebody who knows it.

Comment: ok thanks I am going to try other ways

Answer (score 2):

When you call a method you have to prefix it with the object you want to call it. Here the object is `self`, so instead of simply calling `createImage(imgL, imgR)` you have to call it like this `self.createImage(imgL, imgR)` same things for `createImageRed` and `createImageCyan`

as noted as a comment to this answer you still have undefined names `pathL` and `pathR` you must replace them by `self.pathL` and `self.pathR` in the `openFile*` methods and in the  `sustractBands`, not using them as parameters of `substractBands` and finaly connecting it with

```
self.btn_Convertir.clicked.connect(self.sustractBands)
```

It's because the variables are by default locals to the methods and to be able to go out of a method you have to, in order or goodness either return them, use attribute (which I did) or declare them as global

Comment: ok, but I still have undefined name imgL and imgR, that are the paths of the  2 images that I am loading with qfiledialog, what can I do in this case?